# Extended rules from Styled-Components not working

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components and trying to extend some rules using nested components, but for some reason is not working:

```
const Header = styled.div`
    ${border
      ? `
      border-top-width: 0px !important;
      border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
      border-left: 8px solid ${Base.AzulBordaCard} !important;`
      : null}
  `;

const Link = styled.a`
    padding: 0.7rem 0.8rem !important;

    &:hover {
      background: ${Base.CinzaFundo} !important;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
    }

    &[aria-expanded='true'] ${Icon} {
      color: ${Base.CinzaMako} !important;
      transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
    }

    // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    &[aria-expanded='true'] ${Header} {
      border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    }
  `;
```

Comment: After some tests, I got what @Deve said below. I did the same with Icon and Link, but this guys was nested elements. The same, can't be done with Header since it is above Link and Icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I say no stupidity, you can not access to parent into a child. You can not go up a waterfall. To do what you want, you can pass a prop into your parent component `Header` to handle border bottom. I do a basic example with background to show you how: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-newton-7zxhm. Tell me if it's good

Comment: You're right, I've solved the situation adding a expanded class to the Header also.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `color` and `style` for the `border-bottom` in the last block.

Should be:

```
  &[aria-expanded='true'] ${Header} {
    border-bottom: 1px solid ${Base.AzulBordaCard} !important;
  }
```

Alternatively you could keep the last block as it is and just define a default border all around by modifying the `Header` definition like so:

```
const Header = styled.div`
  border: 0 solid ${Base.AzulBordaCard} !important;
  border-left-width: 8px !important;
`;
```